# How to resolve the URLs conflict in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

How to resolve this ambigious rules conflict:

```
url(r'^help/(?P<page>\w+)/$', 'ecc.views.help_page', name='help_page'),
url(r'^help/search/?$', 'ecc.views.help_search', name='help_search'),
```

When I go to: site.com/help/search, from the Django's point of view, I go to help/page. How to set the priority on this rule?

Answer (score 4):

The order gives the initial priority, so just put the `help/search/` rule above the other one and it will work.